# How do I proof this in Number-Theoretic Function?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, real-numbers, prime-factorization

Show that $\sigma(p^n)=\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}$ , where $p$ is prime.

I know I can't take for granted for just plugging a question and request for the solution.
But I have tried it by using the proof of $\sigma(n)$ but somehow my solution is not convincing, and I think I am not in the right path. Can anyone please guide me? Will appreciate it alot...

This is the formula for $\sigma(n)$ :

[image]

Comment: What's $\sigma$?

Comment: Hi @DanielHast, I have edited my question ya, the σ is as shown at the picture above, it is the sum of the divisor of a number :D

Comment: For $n=p^n$, the only positive factors of $n$ are $1,p,p^2,\dots,p^n$, now sum the geometric series.

Comment: For the general result, show that $\sigma$ is multiplicative and conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything to prove it. If $p$ is a prime, the only prime divisor of $p^n$ is $p$. Also, for all natural $k \leqslant n$, we have $p^k | p^n$, and these are the only divisors of $p^n$ since $p$ is a prime.

Thus, $$\sigma(p^n)=1+p+p^2+\cdots+p^n = \frac{p^{n+1} - 1}{p-1}$$

Comment: oh! Thank you very much!